# Find a table in word and write in that table using java

Tags: java, word-automation

I have a word document which may have n number of tables. The table is identified by the table name which is written in the 1st cell as heading. Now i have to find the table with table name and write in one of the cell of that table. I tried using apache-poi for the same but unable to figure out how to use it for my purpose. Please refer to the attached screen shot, if i am not able to explain how the document looks like.

Thanks [image: as seen in screenshot name of tables are S1 and S2]

```
    String fileName = "E:\\a1.doc";  

    if (args.length > 0) {  
        fileName = args[0];  
    }  

    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);  
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  

    Range range = doc.getRange(); 
    for (int i=0; i<range.numParagraphs(); i++){ 
       Paragraph tablePar = range.getParagraph(i);

        if (tablePar.isInTable()) {  
            Table table = range.getTable(tablePar);  
            for (int rowIdx=0; rowIdx<table.numRows(); rowIdx++) {  

                for (int colIdx=0; colIdx<row.numCells(); colIdx++) {  
                    TableCell cell = row.getCell(colIdx);  
                    System.out.println("column="+cell.getParagraph(0).text());  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

this is what i have tried, but this reads only the 1st table.

Comment: @ADG, you should post that as a response.  POI is definitively the most mature word library.

Comment: removed selenium tags.. don't know why you linked it

Comment: @tom pasted as answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've found u get misunderstanding in poi.
If u just meant to read a table.Just use the TableIterator to fetch the table's content or u will get an exception with not start of table.

I suppose there is only one paragraph in every table cell.

```
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);  
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  

    Range range = doc.getRange();
    TableIterator itr = new TableIterator(range);
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Table table = itr.next();
        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.numRows(); rowIndex++){
            TableRow row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
            for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.numCells(); colIndex++){
                TableCell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
                System.out.println(cell.getParagraph(0).text());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Apache POI is the way to go. It's not well documented, but the time spent on research how to use it may be worth it. Word document is basically a hierarchical (tree) structure which you need to traverse and find the data you need.

Comment: I tried using Apache POI but unable to find a specific table.